# Trouble using psql meta-commands in php for \copy export csv

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to export a csv file from a linux machine to a local PC via a PHP script on a browser.

I've done a good bit of research, but I can't find what I'm looking for (maybe it doesn't exist).

My script connects to the database via php and uses localhost as do my other php scripts that just display data from the database but don't export the data.

Here is my futile attempt:

```
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'XXXXX';
$db = 'ltg';
$host = 'localhost';
$conn=pg_connect('dbname ='.$db.' user = '.$user.' password = '.$password.' host = '.$host) or die ("Could not connect: ");

//query for copying/exporting to csv
echo "system(\copy (select lat, lon from ltg_data order by time desc limit 1000) To '~/Downloads/export.csv' CSV HEADER);"
```

There are two issues, at least, that I'm confused about.  The connection to the db works fine for accessing/display data from db.  Do I need to use something other than "localhost" to export data?

Second, running the \copy command is problematic.  I somehow need to run a psql meta-command to export the data, and I really don't know how to do that via php.

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `system` runs a shell command (not sure why you're echoing it?), so it doesn't go through `$conn` at all. And of course there is no shell command called `\copy`.

If you want you can send a `\copy ...` to `psql` with something like `system("echo '\copy ....' | psql")`, but you'll have to be careful with escaping the parameters etc.

Since your database is on `localhost` and you're already connecting with the `postgres` user, you could just use `COPY` instead of `\copy`, and send the command via `$conn`.

Here is documentation about [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: Thanks very much!  I think i'm getting somewhere.  Here's what I have: system("echo '\copy (Select lat, lon, time from ltg_data order by time desc limit 1000) To 'export.csv' CSV HEADER' | psql");   

It looks like it runs in the browser, but it's not depositing the data anywhere that I can find.  Any suggestions?  I don't think I need any more escaping parameters.  Thanks!

Comment: I would give it a full path instead of just `export.csv` so that you know where to look!

Comment: I gave it...'C:'\export.csv'.  I escaped the "\".  Do you think I need to escape anything else?  Not finding the file anywhere.

Is there any way to tell what it's trying to do when it executes?  Maybe that's a downside of using system.  I tried the regular COPY command with no luck.  

Thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure `system` isn't failing? It doesn't look like you're giving `psql` any arguments for user/database/hostname/port.

Comment: Sorry, I've given up based on the time I have to work on this.  Just want to let you know so you don't spend any more time on it.  I'm simply now just echoing comma separated data on to the screen, and the user can copy/paste if they wish.

I do really appreciate your help, and sorry I didn't come to that conclusion earlier.